# what is best classification that can be used with NER?

Tags: classification, named-entity-recognition

I want to do comparison of classification techniques but now i only have SVM as one of the techniques. Can anyone suggest another technique other than CRF and MNB? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For this, you may consult [paperswithcode in the NER category](https://paperswithcode.com/task/named-entity-recognition-ner), where you will see that in most datasets multiple top performers are BERT-based solutions.

This approach normally consists of taking a pre-trained neural network model that is some variation of the [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) architecture (Transformer encoder trained on a masked language model loss) and fine-tuning it on your data.

You can have a look at the [Huggingface Transformers python library](https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html#named-entity-recognition), which is well suited for this.